# Can I submit bitmaps to be used for PCB silkscreen?

Tags: pcb-design, pcb-fabrication

I have an image which I would like to silkscreen on my PCB. It's quite detailed and when I import it into my editor (I am using the easyEDA web editor) the software simplifies it before it imports it. I believe this is because it coverts it into a vector.

Is this image vectorisation a requirement of the Gerber standard or is there some way I could submit the original bitmap image to be used to create the silkscreen?

I have contacted the production house (JLPCB) and they said this was a design issue.

[image]

Comment: That would be entirely up to the PCB vendor so ask them. "Silkscreen" on a PCB isn't intended for halftone imagery so the vectorised version is probably as good or better than you can expect on the PCB. Send Gerbers and you don't have to worry about the vendor's process.

Comment: Also consider trying to convert it into an importable vector image format youself first, if there is a way to import vector graphics, so you're not just at the whims of the easyEDA bitmap import code.

Comment: Halftone wasnt something i was concerned with, just the fidelity of the print. As i said i did ask them about this and didnt get anywhere but may try again...unfortunately the easyEDA editor only allows the importing of DXF vector files and these are only outlines (no infills) - could anyone recommend any software which will allow the importing of vector files? (preferably free)

Comment: What DPI are you expecting? AFAIK, you're not likely to get better than 200-300 from the silkscreen process.

Comment: its not so much the dpi but the simplification which the image undergoes (similar to using image trace in adobe illustrator if anyone's familiar with that) - its fine when the image is smaller but i want to create quite a large image (big PCB) and this simplification is apparent when the image is large.

Comment: Can you share an example in images?

Comment: hi, i've added an example image with the original bitmap on the right and the processed image in the PCB editor on the left.

Comment: `i believe this is because it coverts it into a vector` I don't think so because there are some very good examples like [this one](http://ncmachineworks.ca/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Visulizer.jpg). I'd really like to tell you how can it be done if I'd really know, sorry. I'm sure the PCB providers know the best.

Comment: I believe that in general the silkscreen process is OK for any line drawing with around 5mil (0.005") line widths. If you try to make the lines thinner than that you will end up with garbage. If you import your gerber into a gerber editor you can select the lines and set the width to whatever you want. Viewmate is one. They have a minimal feature free version and a more expensive (like 100 bucks or something) pay version that can definitely edit and save gerbers (if the free one can't).

Comment: Oh, and spaces between lines may be removed if the spaces are too small.

Comment: @ Rohat Kılıç - thanks for that example, that is definitely created from a raster image so it renews my faith that it can be done...

Comment: @mkeith - thanks for the tip, the problem is that my gerber file already contains the preprocessed vector image and would take a lot of manual labour to edit the image back to how i want it. what i really would like is to be able to add a non processed botmap to my gerber file to generate the silkscreen...

Comment: Well, you can delete the crappy image from your gerber file, import a DXF, select it and set all the track widths to different values until it looks OK to you. Maybe it will work. Maybe it won't. But most people do not attempt to put graphic art on the sikscreen layer, so there is not a lot of support for what you are trying to do. The other note I have for you is that copper layer lithography is better.

Comment: Gerber files are fundamentally vector graphics as far as I know. If you open up the files in a text editor you will get a sense of it. Your image will need to be converted into a series of line segments, arcs, and flashes somehow if you wish to represent it in a gerber file. This may be of interest: https://www.ucamco.com/files/downloads/file/81/The_Gerber_File_Format_specification.pdf?dd1347f8978ee2fb4532ef5613d36e70

Comment: instructables.com/id/Adding-Custom-Graphics-to-EAGLE-PCB-Layouts/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just used Eagles BMP import and have got really good results. it seems to scan through the image and converts the pixel data into lines so is probably how the image which Rohat Kılıç poseted was created.

[image]

Comment: Wow that looks great. I believe the system will block you from accepting your own answer until after 24 hours have passed. If nobody provides a better answer in that time frame, you can accept your own answer (or whichever answer you think is best). It would be cool when you have the actual PCB if you remember to take a picture and add it to the answer so people can see what the finished product looks like. Take care and good luck.

Comment: one drawback is that the image is composed of many many lines so it does cause my computer to slow down a bit when i interact with the image but i am very happy with the detail. thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Since there are probably not hard and fast rules to this, I will give you my marginally informed opinion.

To the best of my knowledge, no, you cannot submit bitmaps to a PCB fabricator. PCB fabrication houses work from gerber files. Any silkscreen artwork must be converted into the gerber format in order to be reproduced on a PCB.

The gerber format basically allows you to draw arcs or lines and to flash apertures. An aperture is an arbitrary shape which may be "flashed" onto the relevant layer. Rectangle and circle apertures are default, pre-defined apertures. Basically the aperture can be thought of as an opening in a screen where ink will be applied. Arc and line width may be varied arbitrarily, however, there is probably a minimum acceptable line width that is vendor-dependent. I think 0.005" (0.13mm) may be a ballpark number for silkscreen layers.

Apertures are solid images, not outlines. The purpose of the aperture is to allow odd shaped pad sizes for components. There will obviously be some resolution limit on features in an aperture. Features that are 0.005" (0.13mm) or smaller may not reproduce very well. It would probably be best to think of the aperture in terms of drawing the outline with a 0.005" (0.13mm) wide pencil on a square grid with 0.010" (0.25mm) grid spacing.

If you can produce your artwork within these constraints, it may be reproduced acceptably on the PCB.

As far as I know there is no limit to how many custom apertures may be created. An entire image could conceivably be created using thousands of unique apertures.

The copper layers support noticeably higher resolution. In some cases, you may be able to put your artwork in the top or bottom copper layer. This is still clearly visible, but in a more subtle way compared to silkscreen artwork. There is a lot of vendor variation in minimum line width in copper layers, and it also depends on how thick the copper is (18 micron vs 35 micron, etc). Check with the vendor on minimum copper track width for your board. Often, for boards with 35 micron copper, the minimum track width on copper layers is 0.004" (0.1mm). But finer widths are available with better suppliers. These finer widths may make the PCB more expensive.

As far as actual conversion of artwork to gerber, I really don't know if there are sophisticated tools available to do it either intelligently or with fine-tuned control. For absolute best results, it might be wise to start with line drawings where the minimum line width and minimum space between lines is 0.005" (0.13mm), and import these as vector graphics. Large areas which need to be filled can be filled with repeated lines, or with simple shapes such as rectangles and circles.

Also, avoid splines. Gerber files do not natively support splines. They must be approximated as multiple arcs or straight line segments.

You can find extensive detailed technical information about gerber files here:
https://www.ucamco.com/en/gerber

Gerber files are text files which can be read using text editors. Perhaps it would not be too difficult to write a script to inject custom artwork into a gerber file.

Comment: thanks very much for this detailed response, it has clarified clearly the nuances of the gerber format.

Comment: It has been my practical experience when designing silkscreen features (i.e. font line widths and component outlines) that using 7mil lines leads to decent screening results. At 5mil the lines can be chancy of them being on the resulting PCB or not. A line may very well not be continuous or some texts may not be fully formed characters.

Comment: It's a little sad that the electronics industry is "gimped" by a 50 year old file format. Everyone seems to just print the "silkscreen" with a giant inkjet now anyway.

Comment: When reading up prior to answering this question, I discovered that the gerber 3x format is now being promoted. I did not look into what the changes are. I guess the current gerber standard is good enough to prevent anyone from trying very hard to find something newer or better.